# How to manage .git on heroku app

Tags: git, heroku

I'm a novice developer and I have some understanding of how git works but I can't figure this one out.  I've got an app on heroku that is just over the max slug size.  Most of my data is in `.git/objects/pack`.  I've done a `gc` and `gc --prune` and it has shrunk it by about 10%.

Can I add .git to my .gitignore file to keep it from pushing to heroku, or is it necessary to manage my app via git?

Are there any other ways to reduce the size of my `.git/objects/pack` without pruning on a more recent date?

Thanks.

Comment: you can't remove git from your heroku app, but you can search for big files in your repo and remove them from the history. take a look to this post http://naleid.com/blog/2012/01/17/finding-and-purging-big-files-from-git-history/

Answer (score 1):

**Do not remove your .git folder with .gitignore.  It'll go bad.**

First step is to remove big stuff from the history:  http://naleid.com/blog/2012/01/17/finding-and-purging-big-files-from-git-history/

Then remove big/unneeded stuff from your slug:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#ignoring-files-with-

If it's still a problem, raise a ticket with Heroku Support and they can GC your repo or even rebuild it.

Comment: In addition, if you have a lot of static assets (images, JS, CSS, etc.) eating up space, those will be the ones you want to add to `.slugignore`. If you aren't doing so already, serve them from somewhere else (S3, CloudFlare, etc).